# How to detect keypress anywhere on panel?

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I have a screen that has multiple search parameters and displays the results in a table that uses paging. The user wants to be able to hit page up or page down to change pages on the table without having to touch their mouse. How would I go about doing this in GWT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a KeyUpHandler to your view. Detect if a key code equals arrow up or arrow down. If it does, change the page number and refresh the table.

UPDATE:

This is how you add a KeyUpHandler to a Composite widget:

```
myPanel.addDomHandler(new KeyUpHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onKeyUp(KeyUpEvent event) {
        if (event.getNativeKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_DOWN) {
            // Reduce page number
        }
    }
}, KeyUpEvent.getType());
```

Comment: No function "addKeyUpHandler on Composite, EntryPoint, or Panel. This is why I'm having this problem.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin It should be `new KeyDownHandler()`.

Comment: @Braj - I prefer to use KeyUpHandler.

Comment: That works quite nicely. Is there a way to then not have the browser scroll? Tried event.stopPropagation() but that didnt work.

Comment: event.stopDefault();  And you can accept the response :)

Comment: No stopDefault()... assuming you meant preventDefault(). Either way, it didn't work. A quick google search said IE doesn't like preventDefault so maybe this is as good as we can get unless you have another idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
Element body = getElementByTagName("body");
        Event.sinkEvents(body, Event.ONKEYDOWN);
        Event.setEventListener(body, new EventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
                System.out.println("ok");
                 if(Event.ONKEYDOWN == event.getTypeInt()) {
                     Window.alert("ok");
                      System.out.println("KeyDown");
                 }

            }
        });
}

/**
 * Gets an element by its tag name; handy for single elements like HTML,
 * HEAD, BODY.
 * @param tagName The name of the tag.
 * @return The element with that tag name.
 */
public native static Element getElementByTagName(String tagName) /*-{
  var elem = $doc.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
  return elem ? elem[0] : null;
}-*/;
```

Comment: how to know that its key that is not a part of input text?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
    Event.addNativePreviewHandler(new Event.NativePreviewHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onPreviewNativeEvent(final NativePreviewEvent event) {
            if (event.getTypeInt() == Event.ONKEYUP) {
                if (event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_LEFT) {
                    System.out.println("left key is pressed");
                } else if (event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_RIGHT) {
                    System.out.println("right key is pressed");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode() + " is pressed");
                }
            }
        }
    });

    DOM.sinkEvents(composite.getElement(), Event.ONKEYUP);
```